# python significant figures and float

Tags: python, floating-point, significant-digits

I'm do not understand why 1.1 + 2.2 is not 3.3 if a computer calculates this.
I am trying to understand the working of binairy floating points.. but I am not even sure of that float the cause is. could you explain this to me?, I have not been able to find a clear explanation.

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
>>> 1.1+2.2
3.3000000000000003
>>>
```

Comment: This isn't specific to python -- This is how it works with any programming language which uses IEEE floating point representation and arithmetic.

Comment: I use python as my example because it is the only language I use

Comment: Yes, this is just a feature of floats.  Read about them on wikipedia and you will understand this behavior.

Comment: You can find it useful http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html